# How to tie my Exact Target account with my Stage Exchange OAuth login?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, developer

I am a new user. I have an existing Exact Target account with my company.  How do I tie that account with the Application I want to create.  I would like to use the Force API to query some of our company mailing data we have collected in Exact Target.

I have already created an application and it can query Exact Target data but it does not seem specific to my companies Exact Target account.  It would seem that I need to provide some sort of account ID to the API.

Comment: Can you please provide some more details, like code for example, of what it is you are doing currently?

Comment: I am using the ValidateEmail REST api:

Comment: string strURL = string.Format("https://www.exacttargetapis.com/address/v1/validateEmail?access_token={0}", authToken);

Comment: Does my authToken need to be tied to a user who already has their ExactTarget account synched up?  I guess I just need to know that when I query ExactTarget, it is for my companies account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you have created an app in AppCenter, based on "I have already created an application." If you haven't gone through that process and recieved your `clientId` and `clientSecret`, you will first want to do the following:

> Visit [App Center](http://code.exacttarget.com) and register as a
>   developer, then create a new app in App Center. Store the clientId and
>   clientSecret for your app (API Keys) in a secure, server-side
>   location.

The [validateEmail route](https://code.exacttarget.com/api/address-validateemail) isn't a route that is account specific, but more of a utility tool to check email addresses.

In order to verify that your account is being accessed properly, try running the [tokenContext route](https://code.exacttarget.com/api/retrieve-tokencontext).

**Sample Call**

```
GET https://www.exacttargetapis.com/platform/v1/tokenContext/
```

**Sample Respone**

HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted

```
{
    "enterprise": {
        "id": 1081365
    },
    "organization": {
        "id": 1081365
    },
    "user": {
        "id": 1093240
    }
}
```